import of a function from nested structure
Consider this directory structure:
a-a
   | b
      | c
          | print.py

Basically a-a/b/c. and print.py inside that directory. The contents of print.py looks like as :
def print_5():
  print("5")


def print_10():
  print("10")


I want to import and use these functions into my current file at the level of a-a. Structure :
ls
a-a     test.py

How do I do that?
Inside test.py, I tried importing all the functions as :
from a-a.b.c import f

print_5()

And it gives error as SyntaxError: invalid syntax that I understand. So, I moved 'a-a' to 'a_a' and it started to give me ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'a_a'. I know it can be a trivial thing, just not coming in place for me.

Where is your top-level or project root? Is it at a-a, or is it the directory above a-a?

Show us the exact command you are using to execute test.py.

Also, if you have renamed a-a to a_a, please fully update the question to show that.  It's confusing when part of the question still refers to the old name.

Assuming a-a is the root directory, you first need to update to a_a as you have already done. Python modules cannot contain -.
You should also add an __init__.py in each directory to mark it as package that can be imported. Your directory structure should look like:
a_a/
├── __init__.py
├── b/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── c/
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── print.py
└── test.py

You also need to ensure that the parent directory of a_a is in your python path. You can either run your script from the parent directory or update the PYTHONPATH environment variable.
Your test.py would import like this:
from a_a.b.c.print import print_5, print_10


I replace filename print.py to  c_print.py and it's work fine:
a_a
├── __init__.py
├── b
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── c
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── c_print.py
└── test.py

test.py
from b.c.c_print import print_5

print_5()

And you also need to make sure that there is a file in the modules
__init__.py
